# c program to print look and say sequence

Tags: c, printing, sequence

this is my code the actual output and required output differs slightly.
in actual output each number is getting printed at new row.
but i want output to be printed in single row separated by space.

Required output

Sample Input :

1 8

Sample Output:

1 11 21 1211 111221 312211 13112221 1113213211

my code is here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *a = malloc(2), *b = 0, *x, c;
    int cnt, len = 1,i=1,lim,s;
  scanf("%d",&s);
 scanf("%d",&lim);
    for (sprintf(a, "%d",s); (b = realloc(b, len * 2 + 1)); a = b, b = x)
    {
        puts(x = a);
        for (len = 0, cnt = 1; (c = *a); )
        {
            if (c == *++a)
                cnt++;
            else if (c) 
            {
                len += sprintf(b + len, "%d%c", cnt, c);
                cnt = 1;

            }

        }
      if(i==lim)
        break;
      i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

my output

input > 1

> 8

output> 1

11

21

1211

111221

312211

13112221

1113213211

Comment: with all due respect and benefit of the doubt (ths could be an exercise in C coding): the code looks a tad complicated (mind you I love pointers and dynamic code). Do you understand the overhead of memory allocation (and re-allocation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> puts automatically appends a newline. If that's not what you want, you can fputs your string to stdout or use printf.

```
 fputs(x=a,stdout);
```

or

```
 printf("%s ",a);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
 printf("%s ",a);
```

instead of

```
 puts(x = a);
```

Comment: @amit If it worked, you should accept this as answer.